# Android to Android TCP Connection

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, connection

All of the documentation, examples and questions I've seen so far on TCP connections with Android have been between an Android device and a computer. As unreliable as wireless can be, is it possible to make a client-server TCP connection between Android devices over WiFi, and if so, how?

Edit: I guess I should elaborate more on my situation.
My Droid does not respond to ping or accept incoming TCP requests from anything unless I first make the Droid a client and my laptop the server. After this initial connection is established I can then ping from my laptop, or make the Droid a server and my laptop the client. What I can't do is make one Droid the server and another a client, I always get a "No route to host" error.

It feels like there is something blocking incoming connections unless the device initiates a connection to something else, and even then the only request the device will accept is with this device. How can I make my Droid a server that accepts all incoming TCP requests from any device on my local intranet?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can tell you I have the exact same problem on my Samsung Galaxy S II. Could this be some kind of security measure, to try and avoid viruses to propagate between different devices on public Wifi-networks? Some ISP:s may have firewalls designed to protect against this kind of threat, but those firewalls want provide any help if devices on the local net are capable of talking to each other directly...?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Just do like you would do with computer/device connections, except run the client and server code on the devices.

Comment: Running the server on a Droid does not work, as the device does not accept incoming connections unless it had previously initiated a TCP connection as a client with another device. In this case, when the device functions as a server, the only incoming connection it will accept is from the device from the previous session. This is the only way I've gotten my Droid device to function as a server, and even then it doesn't accept connections from any other devices on the local network.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the wifi concepts of access point/client with the tcp server/client concepts?  It may also be that using the phone as a tcp client is triggering getting the wifi into a fully connected and active state - it may tend to time out otherwise.  Perhaps you can have the server ping or query the access point or a dns server or something every few minutes while it is supposed to be active.

Comment: Maybe the OS or some other app is blocking incoming connections? I kind of want to know too, as I have an app that I want to add multiplayer to.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: The issue has nothing to do with WiFi access point, as ping works with other mobile handsets in the same local intranet.
@notverycreative: I was thinking that too, but I don't have any other apps running on the device. I have yet to poke around the kernel, but that might be where the problem is...

Comment: @kurifu I was talking about android shutting down the wifi radio, which it tends to do for power conservation when it has been idle. Connecting as a client may start it back up again.

Answer (score -1):

One of the neat things about the Internet is that the Internet doesn't care whether you are establishing a connection between two PC's, a PC and a phone, or two phones. I would look at the [Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) documentation, that should be enough to get you rolling.

Comment: I have a socket implementation working, the issue isn't connecting devices across the internet, the problem is connection devices on a local intranet, which always produces a "No route to host" error, even with permissions set in the manifest

Answer (score -1):

It's certainly possible. The only problem is figuring out the IP address. I don't expect a phone have a fixed IP... However, if there is a fixed "login" server somewhere in the Web which IP is known to both phones then they can do a handshake via that server and after that continue peer-to-peer.

Answer (score -1):

re; The only problem is figuring out the IP address. I don't expect a phone have a fixed IP.

Try this;
Use the web browser on the phone to log into this website: It should provide you the IP address.

http://whatismyipaddress.com/